# PIL image not displaying inside function

Tags: function, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to display `photo.png` in two different ways: first inside the `mainloop` and then inside a function called `show_photo_in_another_window()`. The code is identical in both. The image displays correctly inside `mainloop` but the function gives a blank window. Why? How to fix it? Thanks in advance. I am using Python 3.8.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def show_photo_in_another_window():
    win2 = tk.Toplevel()
    win2.title('Second window')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("photo.png"))
    tk.Label(win2, image=photo).pack()


root = tk.Tk()

win = tk.Toplevel()
win.title('First window')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("photo.png"))
tk.Label(win, image=photo).pack()

show_photo_in_another_window()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's probably this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why don't you vote for a dupe with it ?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria You are right. I don't really use/know `tkinter` and wasn't that confident it was a dupe and don't like wielding a big hammer when unsure.